# Display map as ellipse

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, bing-maps

I would like to display bing map as ellipse (circle) instead rectangle in WPF (for windows phone), but ellipse allows only brush or image fill. I was trying to convert map to image, but not succeeded and I think, that's not good approach. Any ideas? Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the classic rectangle, then clip it:

```
<Grid Height="100" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">  
    <Rectangle Fill="Green">
      <Rectangle.Clip>
        <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50" RadiusX="40" RadiusY="30" />
      </Rectangle.Clip>
    </Rectangle>
  </Grid>
```

Renders as:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use clipping. Though I don't know if there is a restriction for the map control. Clipping is a way to cut things off according to a predefined area. Have a look at http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/05/silverlight-cliptobounds-can-i-clip-it-yes-you-can/ for a sample